# Prove that $f\circ f = \mbox{id}_x$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Assume that for each $x\in[0,1]$ there is positive integer $n$ such that $f^n (x)=x$. (of course $f^3=f\circ f \circ f$ etc.) Prove that $f\circ f = \mbox{id}_x$.

I have strange feeling that this is about fixed point theorem. But can't really see any idea for solution.

Comment: I think it is more clear it you write n (x) instead n, because n depends on x.

Comment: Prove by contradiction. Suppose that $f^n(x)=x$ for some $n>2$ but $(f\circ f)(x)\neq x$.

Comment: @Masacroso: I don't see what argument you have in mind.  Note that any argument is going to need to use some special property of $[0,1]$, since for instance the statement is not true if you replace $[0,1]$ by a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: First show that $f$ is injective, and hence monotone.  There are then two cases: either $f$ is increasing or $f$ is decreasing.  In each case, use monotonicity to show that if $f^2(x)<x$ (or $f^2(x)>x$) then $f^n(x)$ cannot be $x$ for any $n$.  (In the case that $f$ is decreasing, it is very useful to note that $f^2$ is increasing.)